# How can one create cyclic (and immutable) data structures in Clojure without extra indirection?

Tags: clojure, immutability, directed-graph

I need to represent directed graphs in Clojure. I'd like to represent each node in the graph as an object (probably a record) that includes a field called `:edges` that is a collection of the nodes that are directly reachable from the current node. Hopefully it goes without saying, but I would like these graphs to be immutable.

I can construct directed *acyclic* graphs with this approach as long as I do a topological sort and build each graph "from the leaves up".

This approach doesn't work for cyclic graphs, however. The one workaround I can think of is to have a separate collection (probably a map or vector) of all of the edges for an entire graph. The `:edges` field in each node would then have the key (or index) into the graph's collection of edges. Adding this extra level of indirection works because I can create keys (or indexes) before the things they (will) refer to exist, but it feels like a kludge. Not only do I need to do an extra lookup whenever I want to visit a neighboring node, but I also have to pass around the global edges collection, which feels very clumsy.

I've heard that some Lisps have a way of creating cyclic lists without resorting to mutation functions. Is there a way to create immutable cyclic data structures in Clojure?

Comment: At what granularity do you need immutability? If you construct your cyclic graphs within a function then the necessary mutation of the nodes is "never seen", you get an immutable cyclic graph returned by the function.  See http://clojure.org/transients

Comment: @Alex: this sounds like a really interesting approach. I'm fine with the graph being mutable during construction if necessary. I mainly want to ensure that it's immutable after construction so I can hand it to callers without worry. I haven't been able to figure out how to build a cyclic data structure with `transient`, however. Do you have any example code that illustrates this idea, even for something as simple as a vector with itself as an element?

Answer (score 7):

You can wrap each node in a ref to give it a stable handle to point at (and allow you to modify the reference which can start as nil).  It is then possible to possible to build cyclic graphs that way.  This does have "extra" indirection of course.

I don't think this is a very good idea though.  Your second idea is a more common implementation.  We built something like this to hold an RDF graph and it is possible to build it out of the core data structures and layer indices over the top of it without too much effort.

Answer (score 6):

I've been playing with this the last few days.

I first tried making each node hold a set of refs to edges, and each edge hold a set of refs to the nodes.  I set them equal to each other in a `(dosync... (ref-set...))` type of operation.  I didn't like this because changing one node requires a large amount of updates, and printing out the graph was a bit tricky.   I had to override the `print-method` multimethod so the repl wouldn't stack overflow.  Also any time I wanted to add an edge to an existing node,  I had to extract the actual node from the graph first, then do all sorts of edge updates and that sort of thing to make sure everyone was holding on to the most recent version of the other thing.  Also, because things were in a ref, determining whether something was connected to something else was a linear-time operation, which seemed inelegant.  I didn't get very far before determining that actually performing any useful algorithms with this method would be difficult.

Then I tried another approach which is a variation of the matrix referred to elsewhere.  The graph is a clojure map, where the keys are the nodes (not refs to nodes), and the values are another map in which the keys are the neighboring nodes and single value of each key is the edge to that node, represented either as a numerical value indicating the strength of the edge, or an edge structure which I defined elsewhere.

It looks like this, sort of, for `1->2, 1->3, 2->5, 5->2`

```
(def graph {node-1 {node-2 edge12, node-3 edge13},
            node-2 {node-5 edge25},
            node-3 nil ;;no edge leaves from node 3
            node-5 {node-2 edge52}) ;; nodes 2 and 5 have an undirected edge
```

To access the neighbors of node-1 you go `(keys (graph node-1))` or call the function defined elsewhere `(neighbors graph node-1)`, or you can say `((graph node-1) node-2)` to get the edge from `1->2`.

Several advantages:

1. Constant time lookup of a node in the graph and of a neighboring node, or return nil if it doesn't exist.
2. Simple and flexible edge definition. A directed edge exists implicitly when you add a neighbor to a node entry in the map, and its value (or a structure for more information) is provided explicitly, or nil.
3. You don't have to look up the existing node to do anything to it.  It's immutable, so you can define it once before adding it to the graph and then you don't have to chase it around getting the latest version when things change.  If a connection in the graph changes, you change the graph structure, not the nodes/edges themselves.
4. This combines the best features of a matrix representation (the graph topology is in the graph map itself not encoded in the nodes and edges, constant time lookup, and non-mutating nodes and edges), and the adjacency-list (each node "has" a list of its neighboring nodes, space efficient since you don't have any "blanks" like a canonical sparse matrix).
5. You can have multiples edges between nodes, and if you accidentally define an edge which already exists exactly, the map structure takes care of making sure you are not duplicating it.
6. Node and edge identity is kept by clojure.  I don't have to come up with any sort of indexing scheme or common reference point.  The keys and values of the maps *are* the things they represent, not a lookup elsewhere or ref.  Your node structure can be all nils, and as long as it's unique, it can be represented in the graph.

The only big-ish disadvantage I see is that for any given operation (add, remove, any algorithm), you can't just pass it a starting node.  You have to pass the whole graph map and a starting node, which is probably a fair price to pay for the simplicity of the whole thing.  Another minor disadvantage (or maybe not) is that for an undirected edge you have to define the edge in each direction.  This is actually okay because sometimes an edge has a different value for each direction and this scheme allows you to do that.

The only other thing I see here is that because an edge is implicit in the existence of a key-value pair in the map, you cannot define a hyperedge (ie one which connects more than 2 nodes).  I don't think this is a big deal necessarily since most graph algorithms I've come across (all?) only deal with an edge that connects 2 nodes.

Comment: This is a very cool solution.  I love it. Simple and elegant.  
One small challenge, though: 
Assuming the nodes themselves are immutable structures, if you want to update a node, you would presumably have to `dissoc` the old-node, and `assoc` the new node with the old-nodes value. Easy enough.  But you would also need to do the same in maps of all nodes that reference the new-node as a neighbor.  
Not to hard to solve, though.  Thank you.

Comment: it does have extra indirection.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this challenge before and concluded that it isn't possible using truly immutable data structures in Clojure at present.

However you may find one or more of the following options acceptable:

- Use deftype with ":unsynchronized-mutable" to create a mutable :edges field in each node that you change only once during construction. You can treat it as read-only from then on, with no extra indirection overhead. This approach will probably have the best performance but is a bit of a hack.
- Use an atom to implement :edges. There is a bit of extra indirection, but I've personally found reading atoms to be extremely efficient.